# Problem with multiple domains

Tags: 7, multi-sites, domain-access

First of all, let me apologize in advance as this may be a poorly worded question.  My knowledge of Drupal is limited so I'm not even sure of the exact area where my problem is.  I'm looking for pointers in the right direction so I can do more research on my own for an answer.

**The Original Situation**

I have two domains - let's call them `example.com` and `example.net`.  The site was originally built for `example.net` and it is hosted at BlueHost with the following folder structure:

```
/root
    /public_html
        /drupal
            ... standard Drupal folders
            /sites
                /all (this is where all my site files are)
```

So basically, the entire Drupal installation is in a subdirectory of `public_html`. I can access URL's such as `http://example.net/contact` with no problem.  So far, so good.

**The Wrinkle**

Where it starts to get complicated is when we bought `example.com`.  As the primary domain, it points towards `/root/public_html`.  So, I dusted off my Apache skills and fashioned an **.htaccess** file to redirect .com to .net, like so:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal/ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /rings/$1 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ drupal/index.php [L]
```

**The Problem**

Now, if I go to `http://example.com/contact`, it does come up with a Drupal page, so I know that the rewrite rules are working.  However, I get a page that says that `The requested page "/contact" could not be found.`

I want users to be able to use either domain.  That is, `http://example.com/contact` and `http://example.net/contact` should go to the same page.  So this is where I'm stuck.  I'm not even sure where the general area of the problem is.  Do I need to set up a multi-site configuration?  That doesn't sound right because I'm only running one site.  Is it something to do with the domain access module?  That sounds more like something to run multiple sites of one Drupal installation.  Any pointers at all will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your objective?

Comment: Sorry, I guess I made it more confusing by using `example.com` and `example.net`.  They are both alternate domains for the same site, so I want users to be able to use either domain.  That is, `http://example.com/contact` and `http://example.net/contact` should go to the same page.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Cpanel just point both domains to same siteroot folder.

Otherwise create a symbolic link of folder2 to folder1 where folder1 and folder2 and siteroots of each domain.

Comment: Well first of all, I've already "pointed" the .com domain towards the drupal folder using Apache RewriteEngine.  This is working, as already stated.  So, `http://example.com/contact` is being correctly rewritten as `http://example.com/drupal/contact` but Drupal doesn't want to server that page.

Comment: Pl. re-read my answer.

Comment: If I'm missing something, can you clarify?  Please refer to my directory structure above.  .com is hosted in `/public_html` and .net is hosted in `/public_html/drupal`.  I can't change `/public_html` to a symlink.  I could create another subdirectory such as `/public_html/drupal2` as a symlink of `/public_html/drupal` but I don't see the point of that.  The browser is already being redirected to `/public_html/drupal`.

Comment: Assuming /public_html/drupal2  contains the Drupal install. Just go to /public_html and give command: ln -s /public_html/drupal2/* .;ln -s /public_html/drupal2/.* .;

Comment: Without doing/changing anything more it should work. I've already used this setup.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite may be overly complicated. Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.net$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

This should happen before any of the Drupal code in .htaccess

Ideally, this should go in your apache config file.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that your Rewrite rules would  redirect .net URL's over to .com?  This isn't the solution the client wants, which is to keep both domains and have them access the same pages.  So, `http://example.com/contact` shouldn't change the URL to `http://example.net/contact` but rather keep the .com URL and still work.

Comment: Yes, one domain would be your main domain and the other would redirect. This is good for SEO purposes.

Comment: Yeah, I proposed that solution to the client but he didn't like it.